# my class needs to return longest common prefix using a .txt file, but its throwing me an error. Can anyone find me the issue?

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "zwitterionic"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at longestCompound.shortestStringPrefix(longestCompound.java:31)
    at longestCompound.main(longestCompound.java:10)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

```
public static String readFile() {


 String data = null;
    try {
        File myObj = new File("/Desktop/Github/java-project/Conditional-statement/src/words.txt");
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            data = myReader.nextLine();
            //System.out.println(data);
        }
        myReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}

public static String shortestStringPrefix() {
    String[] str = new String[Integer.parseInt(readFile())];
    String longestComp = "";
    if (str == null || str.length == 0) return longestComp;

    int i = 0;
    for (char c : str[0].toCharArray()) {
        for (int j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {

            if (i >= str[j].length() || c != str[j].charAt(i)) return longestComp;
        }

        longestComp += c;

        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(longestComp);
    return longestComp;
}
```

Comment: The string "zwitterionic" is not a number (at least not in base 10), what are you trying to do?

Comment: find common string char from the txt file and display all the char in one String.
 my declaration `String[] str = new String[Integer.parseInt(readFile())];` is not correct.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a description of what the array `String[] str` should look like with the input word "zwitterionic" you read from the file.

Comment: I don't think your `readFile` method does what you think it does. Currently you are overwriting the variable `data` with the content of each line at each iteration, so at the end the method returns only the content of the last line.